# Utilizar o LIKE junto com o BETWEEN

Tags: postgresql

É possível selecionar dados com o **between** junto com o **like**, por exemplo:

`public.retornotoner.observacao like between 'A%' and 'Z%'`

Ou há algo que possa ser semelhante a isso?

Exemplo de dados:

`Vazio
 Mancha branca
 Residuo`

`public.retornotoner.observacao like between 'A%' and 'S%'`

Comment: Olha, pelo que entendi, você pode resolver isso com um simples like 'A%S%' ou como pretende...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente a pergunta, isto deve dar o resultado que você busca:

```
WHERE LEFT(public.retornotoner.observacao, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'S'
```

[Veja funcionando no Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3a5d/1)